# Can't see my ruleset in the Decision Services tab of the Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: business-rules, ibm-cloud

I deployed my latest ruleset to the Business Rules service instance. However, I did not see it listed in the Decision Services tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was already at the Decision Services tab in the Bluemix console, when I deployed the ruleset. I had to click "Refresh" to be able to see the latest deployed ruleset.